# calculate the average : "TypeError: reduce of empty array with no initial value"

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, average

this is my function to calculate the average of array with objects.
But if myData is empty (no objects), I have "TypeError: reduce of empty array with no initial value"

```
var myData = [{"fruit1": 2,"fruit2": 2,"fruit3": 1},{"fruit1": 2,"fruit2": 1,"fruit3": 1}];
var average =[];
                    var average = myData.reduce(function(a, b, index, self) {

                        var keys = Object.keys(a) ;
                        var c = {};

                        keys.map(function(key) {

                            c[key] = (a[key] + b[key] ) ;
                                if (index + 1  === self.length ) {
                                    c[key] =( c[key] / self.length );
                            }
                                        });

                        return c ;
                    });
```

Comment: So, provide an initial value, or check whether or not the array is empty. What do you want the default average to be?

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be your `objectServices2` has no element in it like below:

```
let objectServices2 = [];
```

If the value is coming from some services, you might want to check why is it empty.

Another fix can provide a default value like below

```
var average = objectServices2.reduce(function(a, b, index, self) {

  var keys = Object.keys(a) ;
  var c = {};


  keys.map(function(key) {
    c[key] = a[key] + b[key] |0 ;

    if (index + 1 === self.length ) {
      c[key] = c[key] / self.length ;
    }
  });

   return c ;
 },123);//  <=====here
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is you are missing the initial value for the reduce function.

As per mdn:

> The reduce() method applies a function against an accumulator and each element in the array (from left to right) to reduce it to a single value.

That accumulator is the value of the previous execution of the function, but for the first value of the array, you have to provide the initial value.

If the output of your reduce function is an object, you might want to initialize the function using an empty object `{}`. If it is a number, maybe `0`, and if you want to return a string, a sensible value to start with would probably be an empty string: `''`. It all depends on what you are computing.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

```
var average = objectServices2
    .reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
         // do your work here
    }, initialValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler alternative that loops through each item of the object in array and calculates average:

```
var myData = [{"fruit1": 2,"fruit2": 2,"fruit3": 1},{"fruit1": 2,"fruit2": 1,"fruit3": 1}];

var { average } = myData.reduce((all, item) => {

    Object.keys(item).forEach(k => {
        all.count++;
        all.sum += item[k];
        all.average = all.sum / all.count;
    });

    return all;

}, {average: 0, count: 0, sum: 0});

console.log(average);
```

Or do the `average` calcaulation after you have total count and total sum of items:

```
var myData = [{"fruit1": 2,"fruit2": 2,"fruit3": 1},{"fruit1": 2,"fruit2": 1,"fruit3": 1}];

var { count, sum } = myData.reduce((all, item) => {

    Object.keys(item).forEach(k => {
        all.count++;
        all.sum += item[k];
    });

    return all;

}, {count: 0, sum: 0});

var average = sum / count;

console.log(average);
```